# Convert date formats

Tags: r

I have a dataframe - in which one of the column has dates in two different formats(d-m-Y and d/m/Y) and it also contains a lot of NAs. The column is of character class. I would like to change the formats of dates into one format (Y-m-d) while retaining the NAs as it is. Can you help - how can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2):

If the dates are in the same order, then use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(df1$Col)
#[1] "2018-05-25" "2018-05-25"
```

If the orders are also different, use `parse_date_time`

```
parse_date_time(df2$Col, c("dmy", "mdy"))
#[1] "2018-05-25 UTC" "2018-05-25 UTC" "2018-05-25 UTC"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col = c("25-05-2018", "25/05/2018"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(Col = c("25-05-2018", "25/05/2018", "5/25/2018"),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: hi akrun,it prints out all values as NAs

Comment: @UmeshAgarwal  As  you haven't provided any example, it is difficult to know.  In my post, I showed some examples based on the description and it is working

Comment: check if your "date" columns are factor or character

Answer (score 0):

### base r

You could replace "-" by "/" (or the other way round) and then use as.Date:

```
 df <- data.frame(Col = c("25-05-2018", "25/05/2018"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 df$Col <- gsub("-", "/", df$Col)
 as.Date(df$Col, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```